# Graph the curve with parametric equations x = (1 + cos(16t)) cos(t), y = (1 + cos(16t))sin(t) , and z = 1 + cos(16t)

Tags: plotting

Graph the curve with parametric equations  x = (1 + cos(16t)) cos(t),   y = (1 + cos(16t))sin(t) , and   z = 1 + cos(16t) .

Comment: ParametricPlot3D[{(1 + Cos[16 t])  Cos[t], (1 + Cos[16 t]) Sin[t], 
  1 + Cos[16 t]}, {t, 0, 10}]

Answer (score 5):

```
foo = {(1 + Cos[16 t]) Cos[t], (1 + Cos[16 t]) Sin[t], 1 + Cos[16 t]};

plot =
 ParametricPlot3D[foo,
  {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones",
  PlotPoints -> 64]
```

[image]

Viewed from far above

```
Show[plot, Axes -> {True, True, False}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1000}]
```

[image]

2D - Version

```
ParametricPlot[Most @ foo, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 64]
```

[image]

Comment: So you have an upper part of some kind of a flower for your next generative art ;-)

Comment: Yes, actually I have a similar 3D flower question in preparation (how to fill the leaves)  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for this?

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(1 + Cos[16 t]) Cos[t], (1 + Cos[16 t]) Sin[t], 
  1 + Cos[16 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

or perhaps you want something dynamical?

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[{(1 + Cos[16 t]) Cos[t], (1 + Cos[16 t]) Sin[t], 
   1 + Cos[16 t]}, {t, 0, Pi/10*parameter}], {parameter, 1, 13}]
```